# отображение данных в таблице TableView

Tags: java, javafx

Ситуация такая. у меня есть 2 таблицы. В 1-ой хранятся номера договоров, во 2-ой дополнительная информация по выбранному договору из 1-ой таблицы (т.е. когда я выделяю строку из таблицы 1, в таблице 2 могут отобразиться 4 строки относящиеся по выбранному договору, если я выделю другую строку из той же 1-ой таблице, во 2-ой может отобразиться 6 строк) точнее я хочу так сделать, но у меня не получается. 
   Сейчас у меня есть класс `MainData` там я храню все переменные и коллекцию для отображения информации (переменные отправляются в `Label` с ними все отлично поэтому их в код не вставляю), есть сам класс контроллер, где все отображается. Суть мольбы о помощи заключается во второй таблице, в первой все хорошо, но если я хочу отравить данные во вторую таблицу, компилятор жалуется и говорит преобразуй данные в `ObservableValue<String>`, вроде есть какая-то обвертка, что бы мою коллекцию преобразовать в `ObservableValue<String>` но у меня ничего не получается, помогите с отображением инфы плиз.

Класс `MainData`

```
    private final List<String> nameLink;

    public MainData(String numberContract) {
    this.nameLink = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    }

    public List<String> getNameLink() {
        return nameLink;
    }

    public List<String> setNameLink(String nameLink) {
        this.nameLink.add(nameLink);
        return getNameLink();
    }
```

Класс контроллер

```
public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private TableView<MainData> contractTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<MainData, String> numberContractColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<MainData, String> contractColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableView<MainData> linkTable;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // Инициализация таблицы.
        numberContractColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().numberContractProperty());

        contractColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getNameLink()); //Ошибка именно тут.
```

Вырезал всю лишнюю инфу как по мне, но если что-то не понятно, добавлю конечно

Comment: А вы гляньте на [пример](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html) в самом начале и попробуйте без лямды. Возможно вам всего лишь надо сделать приведение типов

Comment: В приведенном фрагменте одна таблица и 2 колонки, в ячейке второй колонки вы пытаетесь отобразить список. По тексту задания нужна вторая таблица (TableView), элементами которой должен быть список, получаемый из выделенного элемента первой таблицы. Т.е. нужно навесить обработчик на выделение в первой таблице, в котором будет заполняться вторая. Также можно рассмотреть использование TreeTableView

Comment: @RuslanP. я просто вырезал случайно больше чем необходимо, по факту у меня 2 таблицы именно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если во второй таблице нужно отобразить содержимое, возвращаемое getNameLink(), то на первую таблицу вешаем обработчик выделения элемента:

```
contractTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ov, o, n) -> {
        if (n != null) {
            detailsTable.setItems(n.getNameLink());
        }
});
```

где `TableView<String> detailsTable` -- вторая таблица.

В MainData nameLink не приводить к List, а использовать ObservableList

```
    private final ObservableList<String> nameLink = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    // ObservableList вместо просто List
    public ObservableList<String> getNameLink() {
        return nameLink;
    }
```

Comment: обработчик у меня есть, правда его надо будет немного изменить, а что качается моей строки `contractColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getNameLink())` то там ошибка не пропала, ведь требуется `Value`, а не `List`

Comment: Я так и не понял, зачем отображать в одной ячейке таблицы список строк? Кажется, что не требуется отдельной CellValueFactory

Comment: Я хочу в дальнейшем, прикреплять в эту таблицу файлы (ссылки на них) которые относятся к выбранному документу из первой таблицы, просто сейчас для упрощения я пишу `String` если Вам интересно посмотреть как это выглядит, да и мне было бы приятно узнать отзыв по моему проекту целиком - https://github.com/Zherikhov/docManager